# ROS Answers SE migration: remove package

Tags: ros, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

How can I remove a certain package which I just downloaded?

Soe

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9767/remove-package/) by [soetommy](https://answers.ros.org/users/442/soetommy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2011-04-19

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you installed it using a Debian Package, just remove it using the same tool you used to install it (Synaptic, apt-get, aptitude...). If you checked out code from a version control system (Git, SVN...) or just downloaded it, you can just safely delete the directory.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can also just move it to somewhere out of your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH in case you might need it later.

---

Originally posted by [Dimitar Simeonov](https://answers.ros.org/users/256/dimitar-simeonov/) with karma: 535 on 2011-04-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2